# Is row based or column based raw input better?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a vendor that is starting to give me some rather large reports on course completions and usage.

They have two formats for the reports:

1. If a student is enrolled in a course, they will have an row entry with basic student and course information for each course.  Fields would be student name, student id, student email, course name, course status, course completion date.
2. Each student would have one row.  Each course would be represented by a different column.  So we would have student name, student id, student email, course name A, course status A, course completion date A, course name B, course status B, course completion date B, course name C, course status C, course completion date C, course name D, course status D, course completion date D...

The good point of report #2 is that it is much smaller than the report #1.  However I am having a hard time getting a handle on executing views and jobs based on a variable column table (as courses get added I don't really know).

I need to make some advanced usage reports and wrap up student info with certain courses and completions.  Is there a reason why one of the raw formats will either make my job easier or make the database perform queries easier?

Comment: I would say that option #2 is designed for people whom want to use Excel Pivot Tables, etc to examine the data.  While option #1, as [@](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james)[Rick James](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james) said in his answer below, is for importing into a relational database.  There will be no reliable way to use option #2 relationally unless you have some guarantees about the column order for given courses  (*i.e.* they're **sorted**).  Use option #1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a database design point of view, #1 is better.  But...  In either case (#1 or #2) you should not populate *your* database with only one table.

You should have these tables (at least):

- Students - one row per student: Student id, name, email
- Courses - one row per course: Course id (created by you), course name
- StudentCourses - one row per student-course pair that exists: student id (but no other student info), course id, status, completion date.